# Как создать почтовое вложение на spring boot, чтобы источник этого вложения мог быть любям (файл, стрим)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Как можно реализовать на джаве класс, описывающий почтовый аттачмент, который можно отправить на рест сервис? Требования такие:

- Аттачмент может быть как файлом, потоком, так и массивом byte[]
- Класс "сообщение" содержит в себе список аттачментов
- Аттачмент надо кодировать base64 и отправлять на сервер

Я пока не могу придумать универсальное решение. Вот что я написал:

```
public class Attachment<T> {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private T payload;
}
```

Хотел, чтобы тип T мог быть любым из трех перечисленных типов, но зашел в тупик. Как архитектурно можно описать вложение, источник которого может быть любям удобным (стрим, массив байт, файл)?

Дополнение. Я хочу написать обобщенный класс (не обязательно дженерик), который позволяет конструировать сообщение любой структуры (внутри набор ключ-значение, который сервер подставляет в форму) и опционально добавлять вложения.

Comment: а если все перед отправкой переводить в поток байт, а на клиенте выводить этот поток байт?И, также, как вы создали тип и имя, просто добавлять тип в начало массива байт, а потом, по приходу этого вложения, читать первые символы массива и на основании них уже формировать объект?

Comment: @Dred, не хочу костылировать свой протокол. Для этого есть протобуф, но он тут вряд ли подходит. Отправлять все хочу в json. Вложения кодируются base64 и вставляются в поля этого джейсона

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
public class Attachment {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private InputStream payload;
}
```